# Some artifacts are miss when using Android Studio(Gradle) and Robolectric

Tags: android-studio, gradle, robolectric

I download [Robolectric Samples](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples) and imported by Android Studio(version 1.2.1.1). Under `android-api-19` I append dependencies like as follows:

```
dependencies {
testCompile "junit:junit:4.10"
testCompile "org.json:json:20080701"
testCompile "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2"
testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
testCompile "org.robolectric:android-all:4.4_r1-robolectric-1"
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-core:3.0-rc2"

}
```

I can see the `json`,`tagsoup`, `shadows-core` and `android-all` libraries by `Project` view. I also can see them under ${GRADLE_HOME}/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 directory. But when I run the project with Gradle Test, errors occurs:

```
Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup -DartifactId=tagsoup -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup -DartifactId=tagsoup -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2

2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.4_r1-robolectric-1

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=4.4_r1-robolectric-1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=4.4_r1-robolectric-1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.4_r1-robolectric-1

3) org.json:json:jar:20080701

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.json -DartifactId=json -Dversion=20080701 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.json -DartifactId=json -Dversion=20080701 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.json:json:jar:20080701

4) org.robolectric:shadows-core:jar:19:3.0-rc2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=shadows-core -Dversion=3.0-rc2 -Dclassifier=19 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=shadows-core -Dversion=3.0-rc2 -Dclassifier=19 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:shadows-core:jar:19:3.0-rc2

----------
4 required artifacts are missing.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a repositories definition in build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes @AlexFlorescu , this is my dependencies configs: `
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3"
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message, you can seewhat Maven repository it is looking at.  I was able to solve this by updating the `settings.xml` file in my`~/.m2` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the Working Directory in the Run Configurations.
It was pointing to wrong directory.

select Run and then Edit Configurations…​. Use the green + sign at the top left corner to add a new run configuration and select Android JUnit. Make your JUnit run configuration look like the following:
 [image]

At Use classpath of module select the app module of your Android application. As Working directory use the directory of your app module. Class is the file which contains your unit tests (in this case your ctivityTest class).